# How do you use the range function to count from 0 to 8 by increments of 1 for each iteration in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, range

I have a triple for loop that creates a 1 row and 2 column collection of numbers starting at 0 0 and going up to 2 2. The third for loop counts from 0 to 8. The code looks as follows:

```
for N in range(0,3):
    for K in range(0,3):
        print(N,K)
        for P in range(0,9):
            print(P)
```

If you run this code you get the obvious output:

```
0 0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0 1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0 2
0 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
...
```

And so on. I want instead of the output of 0 to 8 after the N K printout, instead something that looks like:

```
0 0 
0
0 1
1
0 2
2
1 0
3
1 1
4
1 2
5
2 0
6
2 1
7
2 2
8
```

My first guess was an if statement that said:

```
if P == Q:
   break
```

where Q was several sets of sums and even the N,K array. However, I couldn't figure out the best way to get my
wanted output. I do think an if statement is the best way to achieve my wanted result, but I'm not quite sure of how to approach it. P is necessary for the rest of my code as it will be used in some subplots.

Comment: You could make a 2D array in which the indices would be what you call your row/column and the value would be 1 to 8.

Comment: So you don't actually want a third loop at all?  `N*3+K` would produce that number you're printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is just an increment by one at each print, you can just do compute the index with  `N * 3 + K`

```
for N in range(0, 3):
    for K in range(0, 3):
        print(N, K)
        print(N * 3 + K)
```

## [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/WholeClientsideLibrary)

Comment: Yours works fine, for my specific code instead of printing N * 3 + K I'd just set P equal to that and it works well. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelKlein works too, You can now think about accepting an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to traverse two iterables in parallel.  In this case, one of the iterables is the result of a nested list.  That can be handled by using `itertools.product`, as follows:

```
import itertools

for (N, K), P in zip(itertools.product(range(3), range(3)), range(9)):
    print(N, K)
    print(P)
```